# Redirecting users to different page after pressing <a> tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, redirect

I'm building front-end with Angular and back-end with Ruby on Rails.
I have a tag below and I would like to trigger a function and redirect users to other page when it is pressed.

```
<a class="page-header--transparent-nav-item" ng-click="deleteSession()" 
href="#home">Logout</a>
```

It seems "deleteSession()" is working. But it does not redirect to "#home".
How do I make sure to redirect users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try as shown below.Use [**`$window`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$window) service.

```
 .controller('ExampleController', ['$scope', '$window', function($scope, $window) {

    $scope.deleteSession= function () {
            $window.location.href = yoururlhere;
        };
}
```

Comment: I get an error saying Cannot read property 'location' of undefined.